# Read Files using Rx Java

Tags: android, rx-java, readfile

I have a number of files from a folder, which I am reading and storing its content to the database. How can I perform the same operation subsequently using RX Java? As I have many files to read and It is taking a lot of time in Async Task

```
String path = "some path";
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + files.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FileName -> " + files[i].getName());

         //execute async to read file
        }
```

Comment: RxJava will not make it faster than AsyncTask. Same threading stuff will be triggered on low level. Please show your AsyncTask code.

Comment: Please put your async task as well.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You can replace sync call with async call. As it was already said, it won't be faster. You simply won't block the UI thread while reading the files. Nevertheless, you can find examples of parallel processing here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#parallel-processing. You can divide your file list into "packages", where a number of files is equal to a number of CPU cores of the phone. If the phone has e.g. 2 cores, you can process 2 files at the same time, wait until the end of processing, take next 2 files and so on. It won't be trivial, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your single threaded approach with multithreading in RxJava insanely easily (in comparison without using RxJava).  AsyncTask offers parallel execution using `executeOnExecutor(Executor exec, Params... params)` so your current implementation could be tweaked for an `AsyncTask` to process single files rather complete directories.  However your question was about RxJava.

Multithreading will speed up the file reading - speed improvements will depend on quite a few factors, but the main one being your flash memory sequential read / random read speeds.  Seeing as this will be a cold `Observable` their is really no point using a `Flowable` as back pressure will not come into play here.

pseudo code for implementing some sort of multithreading :

```
    Observable.just(directory)
            .flatMap(dir ->
                    Observable.fromArray(dir.listFiles()))
            .filter(File::isFile)
            .flatMap(file ->
                    Observable.just(file)
                            .map(this::readFileFunctionWithReturn)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())) // execute on multiple threads
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // observe on UI, or choose another Scheduler
            .subscribe(fileResult -> {
                // unordered results
            });
```

You can also create custom `Scheduler` implementation backed by an `Executor` if you want more fine grained control over the threading i.e custom `ThreadFactory`.

Comment: Your code is helpfule. There is just one confusion that before calling the **readFileFunctionWithReturn** function, I need to check if the file is directory or not, if it is directory then call the first flatmap again, or else move with **readFileFunctionWithReturn** function. How can I do that..??

Comment: Your supplied code does none of this? You can't just add expectations in comments - show your existing code that does this.  In order to recursively pick out files and directories you'd need something like `concatMap` / `concatWith`

Comment: Did it..!! Made another recursive observable, which is working for now. Thanks a lot, your answer was very helpful..!!